# Three.js Mesh to Inherit Color from in-front objects

Tags: three.js, overlay, color-blending

**Scenario**

I'm trying to get meshes to inherit color from other meshes that are in physically in front

example:

```
Mesh A       Mesh B       Camera
(white)       (red)

              +---+         |\
  []          |   |      << | ]
              +---+         |/
```

I don't want Mesh B to be visible at all BUT I want Mesh A to be red where Mesh B would be blocking the view of Mesh A. All I can think of is that this is a kind of color overlay.

**Prototype**

[I made a three.js prototype](https://jsfiddle.net/bezm269p/) where two planes are partially blocking the view of a white sphere. I want to be able to turn the plans into a color overlay so that the sphere shows red, white, and blue (accidental usa flag colors)

**Question**

Is there a way to do this with THREE? I'm not fixed to this way of doing things but it seems possible, I just haven't come across the right documentation yet.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the blending mode of each plane's material to `blending: THREE.MultiplyBlending`, so the plane's color is multiplied with items behind it.

See it [in action here](https://jsfiddle.net/marquizzo/1ao6dy7f/).

However, if you want it to apply to **only** the parts where the plane and the sphere overlap, you'd need to write a custom post-processing pass that knocks out the background. Or you could set the background color to `#000`, since multiplying any color by black yields black.

Comment: Smooth move on the Multiply! That totally skipped my mind. I'm ultimately thinking that I'm going to have to create multiple sphere meshes using a single geometry object, then use the planes to clip certain spheres into view. What do you think ?

Answer (score 1):

check the fiddle [solutionLink](https://jsfiddle.net/ps1f5njg/5/), the two red and blue planes are invisible, a raycaster is shooting from the camera to the scene, when the red or blue planes are hit and the sphere is hit too I change the color of the ball

```
const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
const redMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 'red'});
const blueMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 'blue'});
function raycastFromCameraAndUpdateSphereColor() { // place this in the render loop
    raycaster.setFromCamera( new THREE.Vector2(), camera );
    const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );
    if (intersects.length > 1) {
      // name the object to identify it
      if (intersects[0].object.name === 'redPlane') {
      intersects[1].object.material = redMat;
      }
      // name the object to identify it
      if (intersects[0].object.name === 'bluePlane') {
      intersects[1].object.material = blueMat;
      }
    }
}
```